# How to start other app's activity without bring it to front?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have some specific needs for app A start app B's `Activity` without bring app B to the user, is it possible, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean an invisible layout or a service?

Comment: @sanjeev No, an activity

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the app B's activity, you can add this line in the `onCreate()` method

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

If you can't modify that activity I think it is not possible.

Comment: just to note, I think this will still kind of *blink* a new activity start

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko well, probably yes.... but I think it’s the best solution.

Comment: @FrancescoRe I have tried this, it will bring the app B to the front

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not possible. When you launch an `Activity`, the target task (task into which the `Activity` is launched) will be brought to the front and the `Activity` will be shown. There is no way to "launch an `Activity` in the background".

Comment: Is there a way to not brought the task front

Comment: No. There is no way. What is the problem? What do you need to do? If you need background functionality, there are services and broadcast receivers for this purpose.

Comment: @ David Wasser What I want is to wake up app B.

Comment: What do you mean "wake up"? Please be more specific. Anyway, for background functionality you you a BroadcastReceiver or a Service, not an Activity.

Comment: Wake up means get wake up app B's process, for some reason, Service may be restricted by OS

Comment: Sorry, still don't understand. In any case, you should use Service or BroadcastReceiver for background processing, not Activity